# What is the support of transparent HTML5 videos in browsers?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, web, webm

I need to use this for a project. I don't intend to support any old browser, but this is quite a feature and I have a close-to-the-same fallback for it, so I would like to know in which browsers I should apply this.

Comment: good resource for questions like this: http://caniuse.com/

Comment: Yes, I know, but there's nothing regarding webm alpha channel support